# How to configure the table width inside a landscape page header to be 100%?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word 2010 document with both portrait and landscape pages.

I have a table in the page header, with its width set to 100%.

The problem is that on the landscape pages the header table is only as wide as the portrait pages.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In landscape page header view, go to the Design tab and click the "Link to Previous" button (so it is not highlighted) in the navigation menu. This will allow the landscape page to use the table width property.

[image]